# How to combine object animation with a separately rendered background image

Tags: animation

I have couple of MakeHuman Models talking with each other, in a studio setting. The environment consists of brick walls, wooden floors and furniture. The background does not change from frame to frame. Lighting is also static across frames, and it is OK if I have to turn off shadows completely.

However, the animation rendering takes a long time. I was wondering if it is possible to speed up the animation,  by avoiding the rendering of the background, in every frame, over and over again. Put it another way, is it possible to create one render image of the background and somehow combine it with the character animation done separately?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You can render the background and mix later, but I'm not sure that's going to speed things up for the 3D rendering though.  Have you tried rendering using your PC's hardware - OpenGL?  (Render menu at Top left of the window --> "OpenGL animation")  That's very fast compared to Blender and Cycles.  You could use those renders for reviewing animation etc, and if necessary redo with the Blender engine when all is ok.